# Does network-wide search for tags work only with is:q?

Tags: support, bug, search, per-site-meta

I saw a discussion on one per-site meta today and I wanted to check whether something similar was discussed on some other meta sites. Since tags on various metas often have similar names, it seemed reasonable to try searching using tags. When I was doing that, I have noticed the following:

- If I [search for [down-votes] [statistics] is:q](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdown-votes%5D+%5Bstatistics%5D+is%3Aq), I get some questions from Meta Stack Exchange and from few per site metas.
- If I remove is:q and [search for [down-votes] [statistics]](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdown-votes%5D+%5Bstatistics%5D), I only get results from Meta Stack Exchange.

However, the second search should return more results - after all, I removed one of the conditions on the posts I am searching for.

Have I misunderstood how this is supposed to work? Or is this a bug?

Comment: By the way, belated congratulations on earning 10k here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The bug seems to be fixed:</s>

The 2nd search returns 29 results while the 1st returns 9 results.

---

But, it seems to miss some results, because it shows 15 results on the first page, although 30 results is selected in the bottom of the page by default. If you click on 30 results [you can see all results](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5bdown-votes%5d+%5bstatistics%5d&pagesize=30) and none is missing.

=> So, the bug is actually that 30 results per page is selected by default while only 15 results are shown.

Comment: The bug is that posts like MathOverflow Meta's "Do we use the downvote button more than other sites?" don't show up in the second search (only the first). This hasn't changed.

Comment: @Laurel scroll down on the page with more results and select to show 50 entries per page and you will find it there as well. The bug is fixed.

Comment: Well, you're right, but this seems like a bug in itself. My page size was shown as 30, which should have been enough to show everything. Plus, I thought there was pagination so you could see the rest without having to change the page size.

Comment: @Laurel So now it makes sense to me. The bug is that is displays only 15 entries while 30 is selected. If you click on 30 you will also see all results. I edit my answer.

Comment: Here is an older post related to your observation: [Pagination on stackexchange.com search is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359216).