# "Search all sites", except one

Tags: feature-request, support, search, stackexchange.com

I'd like to [search all sites](https://stackexchange.com/search) for "Wikipedia", but exclude Stack Overflow because the questions there are totally out of the scope I'm looking for.

By reading the [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) page, I see that:

1. I can search on one site only, if I use `url:stackoverflow.com`;
2. I can exclude results, if I use something like `-Wikipedia`.

The problem is: `Wikipedia -url:stackoverflow` doesn't seems to work. I was expecting that it would search all sites excluding Stack Overflow.

Do I get a syntax error for the semantics that I seek, or is this operation not supported by the 'search all sites' feature?

Comment: The `url:` operator does **not** search by Stack Exchange site. It searches for posts which contain a link matching the text you specified. So searching for `url:stackoverflow.com` would search for posts that contain a link to stackoverflow.com within them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For questions *tagged* with 'wikipedia', the alternative is to use [Stack Exchange Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters/). *However, it can only show a total of 100 questions.*

Example for [All questions tagged with 'Wikipedia' except on SO](https://stackexchange.com/filters/434702/all-questions-tagged-with-wikipedia-except-on-so):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible. Somehow, when searching for a term, the results seem ... randomly ordered. Even the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) won't help here - body searches are too heavy for some of the largest sites in the network.

It gets better when you use [search operators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

- `title:"Wikipedia"` returns [questions with Wikipedia in the title](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22Wikipedia%22)
- `url:"Wikipedia"` returns [posts with links to Wikipedia](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22Wikipedia%22)

Then, the results look to be grouped by site, which is probably easier for you to work with - the Stack Overflow results are lumped at the end, so the first few pages are free of Stack Overflow. (The last few pages probably contain non-SO results as well, be sure to check them as well.) Do note that [pagination is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359216/295232)...

As an alternative for common searches, you can visit a regular search engine of your choice and use the `site` parameter. [This is what Google returns for `site:stackexchange.com "wikipedia"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com+%22wikipedia%22). You'll miss out on a few sites (Super User, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu, MathOverflow, Stack Apps) but you can search them separately if you want to.

Comment: I'm not looking for Wikipedia links. I'm looking for questions about Wikipedia (Wikipedia on the title of the page).

Comment: Then try https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22Wikipedia%22 - it doesn't have that many SO results.