# Fix broken links to Virtual Laboratories in Probability and Statistics

Tags: support, status-completed, hyperlinks, broken-link

There are quite a few links in the network ([148 when I'm writing this](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22www.math.uah.edu%2Fstat%2F%22&pageSize=50), mainly on Cross Validated, Mathematics and MathOverflow) to the [Virtual Laboratories in Probability and Statistics](https://web.archive.org/web/20120118144432/http://www.math.uah.edu/stat/) hosted at `https://www.math.uah.edu/stat/` which contains material about probability and stochastics. The material is still available and is now called [Random](https://www.randomservices.org/random/). Links like http://www.math.uah.edu/stat/expect/Spaces.html (from [this randomly chosen post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/118635/79696)) redirect to Random's homepage, but it would be a lot better if visitors were directed to the page itself.

I have a script which can do this, but this time the substitution is so straightforward that [the mass link updater tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/295232) can be used by staff members to fix them at once, without bumping the affected posts to the front page. All it needs to do is find `www.math.uah.edu/stat/` and replace it with `www.randomservices.org/random/`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have swapped out the URLs for all the links that I could find, in both posts and comments, except for a handful of exceptions that I couldn't touch due to length (changing the URL would have pushed the comment beyond the maximum length, and I don't want to take editorial liberties to make them fit).

Here are the posts (both questions & answers) and comments I've found on each site, and fixed or not fixed:

| **Site** | **# of posts changed** | **# of comments changed** | **# of comments ignored** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cross Validated | 68 | 38 | 3 |
| Mathematics | 94 | 63 | 3 |
| Math Overflow | 6 | 3 | 0 |
| Physics | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Stack Overflow | 6 | 4 | 0 |

This adds to more than 148 because [the search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22www.math.uah.edu%2Fstat%2F%22&pageSize=50) only yielded questions but, in some cases, there were multiple answers that contained relevant links as well.

I know the `Id`s of the comments I left alone, and during business hours I will look more closely to see if I can do something creative to make them fit without affecting substance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick fix! Now I'm wondering why that search didn't include answers...

Comment: @Glorfindel I think in cases where a question and at least one of its answers is returned by the search, you only get one result?

Comment: That would be a plausible explanation, but [this search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fa%2F322000%2F350567%22) seems to suggest otherwise. Well, without another example, it will be hard to fix the bug that caused it ...

Comment: @Glorfindel Well, something was definitely funky with your search anyway, you said there were 148 results (and I believe you) but when I browsed through them to see what we were looking at, there were 4 pages (@ 30 per page), and every single post except this one was from Cross Validated. So I was only seeing <= 120 results. I cleaned up one site at a time, starting with Cross Validated, and after a few minutes suddenly the search re-populated with the results from the other sites. I don't know if I can explain that behavior either, except that perhaps 148 wasn't accurate either.

Comment: That's a [known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359216/295232) ...

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, nav/pagination is broken, which leads me to mistrust my count of 120, but I still ended up modifying more posts than even your search yielded, which was more than mine yielded. I trust the database results more than the search in any case. :-)