# Global search doesn't include all questions tagged [community-standards]

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, global-search

Global search doesn't include questions tagged `[community-standards]` from Community Building, only from Meta Stack Exchange.

---

[[community-standards] is:question](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcommunity-standards%5D+is%3Aquestion) returns 47 questions, all from Meta Stack Exchange.

[image: Stack Exchange global search results]

Copy-pasting the search box content into the search box of [Community Buiding](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/) returns 16 results

[[community-standards] is:question](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcommunity-standards%5D+is%3Aquestion)

On the other hand, searching [[community] is:question](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcommunity%5D%20is%3Aquestion) returns posts from multiple sites (more than 5k results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a list of only 15 questions, which you can quickly verify by searching [for "asked" on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m06o.png). By manually adding [`&pagesize=50`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5bcommunity-standards%5d+is%3aquestion&pagesize=50) to the URL, you can see all the results, including the ones on Community Building.

The bug here is that the navigation is removed — there is no way to change the pagesize from the page you linked, nor is there a way to go to subsequent pages of results. This seems to be the same issue as in [Pagination on stackexchange.com search is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359216/323179).

Comment: One thing that bugs me is that the bug is not always present. The other search that returned multiple sites on the first page and +5k results did not have this problem.